# Количество натуральных чисел состоящих из более чем a цифр и менее чем b цифр

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Пытался решить такую задачу: "Сколько существует натуральных чисел состоящих из не менее чем a цифр и не более чем b цифр." Эти числа не превышают 10 000.
Вот мой код:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int a,b,c,d;
    cin >> a >> b;
    c=1;
    d=1;
    b=b+1;
    for (int i=1; i<a; i++) c=c*10;
    for (int i=1; i<b; i++) d=d*10;
c--;
d--;
    cout << d-c;
}
```

Проверял - всё работает, однако на полный балл не заходит. Понимаю, что мой код не может работать с числами с 10000 знаками, однако не знаю как это исправить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cin >> a >> b;
for(int i = 0; i < b-a+1; ++i) cout << 9;
for(int i = 0; i < a-1; ++i) cout << 0;
```

Вроде бы так, нет?

Comment: Большое спасибо, количество пройденных тестов увеличилось ~в 2 раза, однако, все тесты программа всё ещё не проходит.

Comment: А вы дайте URL. Я вам что, волшебник? Может, там сначала может идти большее, потом меньшее - вы же изложили свое видение задачи, не более того. Хотите точный ответ - давайте точный вопрос!!

Comment: Случай, когда a>b разобрал, зашло на полный балл. Спасибо!

Comment: Вот видите - а в условии вы об этом ничего не писали...

Comment: Вот это чит, действительно же можно не считать само число, а просто вывести его поразрядно 

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int c = pow(10, a-1);
    int d = pow(10, b-1);
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = c; i < d; i++, result++);
    cout << result;
}
```

Если перебирать втупую :)

Comment: Ну, дайте, скажем, числа 400 и 500...

Comment: @Harry вопрос был между двумя числами с заданным количеством цифр, разве не так?

Comment: Ну да. До 10000 этих самых цифр. Ладно, пусть будет 40 и 50, я уж не претендую да 400 и 500...